# logic behind multiple web service

Tags: web-services, webservice-client

I am right now writing web service for a system. There is 3 web service namely wsA, wsB, and wsC. The system is for registration system. First user provide information such as username and password, and then in wsA the information is being checked through internal server. if there isn't any information recorded, the parameter is passed to wsB, where wsB is a commercial data server. after getting the information from wsB, the details are then passed to wsC where here the details are saved into internal server. i must avoid or have minimal contact to wsB because though it has data about anything, it is also a pay-per-use system. with all this web service / web service client, i become loss and blank. Help me guys. i need the logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to save all data that you ever receive from wsB and include them in search at wsA. That way you are not "wasting" any data, if you receive something once, you have it for good.